# When does MySQL query cache get flushed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an innodb mysql db, I wanted to know if the query cache gets flushed on any change in the table or it gets flushed when there is a change to only those records?

I have a large table that gets modified every few minutes so I am wondering how useful it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you are talking about the **Query Cache** but about the **Buffer Cache**.
The query cache is a cache of the most recent SQL statements, these are never flushed to disk.

Flushing the buffer cache is not as important as flushing the **buffer log**. The log keeps track of the updated performed on the data inside your databse. It is used to recover the db in event of a failure i.e. when buffer cache is not flushed to disk.

There are 3 main ways to flush the bufferer log in InnoDB and they are controlled with the parameter `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`.
*MySQL docs quote:*

*"If you can afford the loss of some of the latest committed transactions if a crash occurs, you can set the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit parameter to 0. InnoDB tries to flush the log once per second anyway, although the flush is not guaranteed. Also, set the value of innodb_support_xa to 0, which will reduce the number of disk flushes due to synchronizing on disk data and the binary log."*

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html

Hope that helps

Comment: aaah yes the buffer cache sounds like what it want. thanks reading up on innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit option